# Android Toolbar Menu items not showing when I have

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have an `ImageButton`, as well as an `TextView` defined within my `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`.  I also have a menu item, but this is not showing up when I run the app.

I have claeed the `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)` in my activity, but not sure what I am missing here.

Here is my `tool_bar.xml`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_nav_icon"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is my menu item:

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:icon="    @drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

And here is my `HomeActivity.java` class

```
private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
{
    //implement logic here to get selected item
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
}
```

Why is the menu item not showing?

Comment: Try this but i m not sure add theme in your toolbar 
    android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar"

Comment: This requires an API level 21

Comment: <style name="MyToolBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

Comment: I have added the above theme to my styles file, and set the toolbar's style to this, still did not solve it.

Comment: I think the problem is the location of your `menu.xml` file. It should be in `/res/menu/menu.xml`

Comment: @MohammadZ the menu.xml is located in /res/menu/menu.xml
If i remove the ImageButton and the TextView, it displays correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,
 add this code in home.xml

```
<include android:id="@+id/tool_bar" layout="@layout/tool_bar"></include>
```

and also change in style

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: This is exactly what my code was like, well, without the ID, but I copied your solution anyway, and I realized my ID in the include was not set.  I will mark this as solution, as you basically did solve my issue ;-)